# h1 title attribute

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't TITLE tags get indexed in google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9572/why-dont-title-tags-get-indexed-in-google)

Hello there,

I have a h1 element on my page which is working great. I have also been using the title attribute on this element which I don't think has been causing much harm at all. My h1 title is "The Great Ocean Road" and the title attribute on that is "Great Ocean Road" - so it's a variation of the h1 text. These are both keywords for the site so i'm hoping it's a good thing for seo.

Is that a bad idea do you think? I'm not sure what Search Engines think about using a title attribute or even if they would 'mark me down' for doing it in such a way. Do you think if the h1 text is "The Great Ocean Road", the title attribute should be "The Great Ocean Road" aswell?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, search engines don't index or read `title` attributes to determine keyword relevance. The `title` attribute is [usually](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets) supposed to provide users with supplemental (or "advisory") information on an element. It is commonly displayed as a tooltip (or spoken by an audio user-agent).

Repeating your heading in a title attribute to load your page up with more keywords won't provide your users with any benefits or help you rank better. It might, however, get you penalized for over-optimization (being spammy).

You should use meaningful text that provides useful supplementary info to users if you're going to add a `title` attribute to an element.

Comment: Ah o.k. I wasn't overly worried about it but but will bear that in mind. I'm just going to continue being honest in terms of overall SEO, that seems to work :)